# Having trouble async (I think) loading of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a View Controller, which has various inputs, and when a button is clicked, I call prepareForSegue to a UITableViewController, and pass an array that will be parsed into that tableview.

That's all fine and dandy, but the parsing occurs by parsing data from loading it from an internet URL. When this happens, the view stays on that first view controller (not the table one), and the button is shown as clicked (blue) until all the data is loaded, then it segues to the table view (with the parsed data).

What I want to do is have it immediately segue to the table view, and then populate the table view with the parsed data over time as the data is loaded over the network.
What I would think to do is to use GCD to asynchronously load the data in a queue other than the main thread.

The problem is, I can't find anything about this on Google (or am just having trouble).
Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking to do this asynchronously. This [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/) would be a good choice.. Have a look...

Comment: From the AFNetworking tutorial: "Even though Interface Builder is great, I often build my interfaces programmatically, and that is what we will do in this tutorial as well." I pretty much do everything programmatically, but I'm trying to learn Storyboards, so if you are in the same boat, just a heads up about the tutorial.